# Displaying Facebook Images by calling the image source url directly - Do I need the FB API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been asked to update an integration between a php/mysql site and FB, to meet some new requirements and also the new FB API guidelines and submit a new FB App for review.

Up until now, what this integration does, is that it is loading FB page albums images by album ID, and showing them as galleries on the php site. 
Every time there is a request to display an album, there is an API call that will fetch the images urls and load them in the gallery.

FB have notified the app owner that his app will stop working after August 1st. So there is actually to little time to update the integration, and the app and prepare for submission for app review.

So, I am wondering if as a temporary solution I could store the data for all those albums and their images in the site's database, and then load the galleries directly using the images urls that will be stored in the database, without calling the FB API.

I have searched in Google and Facebook, but I couldn't find any specific information if this is something that is allowed or not, as search results are coming mixed due to the keywords used.

Anyone could give me some information on this? 
Would loading the images on the php site directly using images source url be safe and not violate any FB usage rules?

Also, I would assume that images source won't change in time, but could someone confirm that this is the case, so that the stored images data won't become outdated and result in not found errors?

Comment: _"but could someone confirm that this is the case"_ - I would argue that no one can confirm this (with Mark as a possible exception), since we don't know what changes facebook will come up with tomorrow. Using facebook's API's are always risky, since they have a history of changing somethings quickly and without much notice.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson tell me about it ... sometimes they even introduce random bugs out of thin air, which takes down entire login systems. Such a hassle, and another reason why the Fb virus needs to stop being spread ;)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Hey thanks for getting involved here - I actually mean if there is any current mechanism that is changing the images source dynamically each time or in the short term somehow - making the images exist on a new url and not what could happen in the long run if FB changes again its internals.

Answer (score 0):

All FB image urls are signed, which means when you request an URL for the image, you'll get signed URL which works for a couple of minutes (or hours) after which it will expire and new link must be requested.

I don't know if what you do (load gallery page and scrape image links) is against FB's TOS, but it certainly is not the way to do it :) in other words it works now, but it might not work tomorrow. Using FB graph api is safer IMO

Comment: Hey Avram - thanks for the info. Certainly FB graph API is the way to go. Do you have any links where I could read more about the FB images urls?

Comment: Even if it wouldn't be against their current TOS, they will probably change it at anytime know, considering the current spotlight.

Comment: Hi Avram. 3 days later, loading the images using their stored urls in my database, the images links haven't expired yet.

Comment: I don't know what URLs the API is returning but when scraping URLs you should get URLs that expire. At least it should be faster this way